# I'm not sure if my Express Checkouts are Working

Tags: express, paypal, transactions, checkout, express-checkout

How you doing? Well, i'm actually trying to integrate MyApplication > Paypal (at the SandBox mode).
Everything seems to be right and fine.
The api returns me a long message with tokens and stuff(without any error).
But when i look into the transaction logs, nothing is there. 
Can someone help me please? Thanks for your attention!

Return message below:

```
**TOKEN=EC-4AC61708HJ334290N&SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED=false&TIMESTAMP=2017-03-07T12:28:41Z&CORRELATIONID=7c178cc4f1c19&ACK=Success&VERSION=124.0&BUILD=30029726&INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED=false&SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT=false&PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID=28P934681K948924T&PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE=expresscheckout&PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE=instant&PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME=2017-03-07T12:28:40Z&PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT=12.90&PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT=0.84&PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT=0.00&PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE=BRL&PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS=Completed&PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON=None&PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE=None&PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY=Eligible&PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE=ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible&PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID=TMFJLA7Z6JJAG&PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE=0&PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK=Success**
```

Comment: Are you using it for mobile app or web?

Comment: im also using this example
https://github.com/br-paypaldev/code-sample-express-checkout

Answer (score 0):

For sure your transaction is processed successfully as you have the transaction id in the response. Where do you actually look out for the transaction logs?

Comment: i'm actually using this
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/dashboard/sandbox/